# Creating a launch configuration in different region and vpc with Boto

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto

I can't seem to create a launch configuration in a specific region and a defined vpc.

```
aws_access_key_id = 'XXX'
aws_secret_access_key = 'XXX'
ec2_keypair = 'XXX'
ec2_security_groups = ['sg-XXXX']
ec2_region = 'us-west-1'
instance_type = 'm1.medium'
user_data = None

# Build the launch configuration
launch_config = LaunchConfiguration(
    name=name, image_id=image_id, key_name=ec2_keypair, user_data=user_data,
    security_groups=ec2_security_groups, instance_type=instance_type)

# Get the Region
conn = EC2Connection(aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,
                     aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)
region = next((r for r in conn.get_all_regions() if r.name == ec2_region), None)

# Connect to the Autoscaler
conn = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region(
           region, aws_access_key_id=access_key_id, 
           aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)


conn.create_launch_configuration(launch_config)
```

When I run this I get the error `No default VPC`.  This aligns with doing this at the command line (run_instances) so there I've just added the subnet.

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://autoscaling.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-01-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>ValidationError</Code>
    <Message>No default VPC for this user</Message>
  </Error>
```

**Where do I append the subnet or VPC for this to work?**

Comment: Ever find an answer to this? I'm currently getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you need to do this

```
    launch_config = LaunchConfiguration(
        name=name, image_id=image_id, key_name=self.ec2_keypair, user_data=user_data,
        security_groups=self.ec2_security_groups, instance_type=str(instance_type),
        associate_public_ip_address=True, )

    conn = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region(
        self.ec2_region,
        aws_access_key_id=self.access_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=self.secret_access_key)

    conn.create_launch_configuration(launch_config)
```